# Ошибка в Qt5Gui.dll

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qimage

У меня есть задача - вывести текст на изображение. Я вначале пробовал с Pillow, но мне не понравилось. У него очень плохое и неудобное API и он не может добром выводить многострочный текст. Так вот я пытаюсь на Qt сделать теперь:

```
img = QImage('input.jpg') 
painter = QPainter(img) 
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red)) 
painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12, QFont.Bold)) 
painter.drawText(img.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, 'Hello world!') 
painter.end() 
img.save('output.jpg')
```

Но когда доходит до `painter.drawText` падает ошибка виндовая "Прекращена работа программы Python." В подробностях указан модуль `Qt5Gui.dll`. Что-бы это могло значить?

Comment: @Yami у него есть конструктор принимающий объект `QPaintDevice`. Я полагаю это альтернатива вызову метода begin. Хотя пробовал и вызывать - эффект тот же.

Comment: @Yami я же говорю с вызовом begin ошибка не исчезает! К тому же ошибка падает именно на drawText - я дебажил. Оно все равно не доходит до вызова end.

Comment: А это **весь** код вашей программы?

Comment: @mkkik да. Это демо проект, я только тестирую пока-что. Он же - минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Тогда, проблема в том, что у вас нет экземпляра `QGuiApplication` в рантайме. Ошибка сегментации возникает в функции `QGuiApplication::font()`.

Comment: @mkkik точняк, спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mkkik:

> Тогда, проблема в том, что у вас нет экземпляра QGuiApplication в
> рантайме. Ошибка сегментации возникает в функции
> QGuiApplication::font()

Работающий код:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QImage, QPainter, QPen, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QGuiApplication([])

img = QImage(200, 200, QImage.Format_RGB32)
img.fill(Qt.white)

painter = QPainter(img)
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12, QFont.Bold))
painter.drawText(img.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, 'Hello world!')
painter.end()

img.save('output.jpg')
```

output.jpg:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]